# How to add more than one integer to a name in a python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

This is my code and I need to work out the average score for each student but this part of the code is incorrect.It is the part with the stars that I need to fix

```
while choice == 'av'.lower():
    if schClass == '1':
      schClass = open("scores1.txt", 'r')
      li = open("scores1.txt", 'r')
      data = li.read().splitlines()
      for li in data:
        name = li.split(":")[0]
        score = li.split(":")[1]
        **if name not in diction1:
            diction1[name] = score
        elif name in diction1:
             diction1[name] = int(score) + diction1[name]**
```

Comment: `'av'.lower()` is useless, it's just `'av'`.  And the `elif` condition is useless too,  it will always be true.  Anyway you haven't actually told us what's wrong?

Comment: It is the last line , adding more than one score to a name

Comment: Make `diction1` a `defaultdict(set)` (or `defaultdict(list)` if you need order) from the collections module.

Comment: You need to declare default `diction1`

Comment: What is `score` ? String? List? Only one integer?

Answer (score 0):

How does the file look like?

```
A: 10
B: 10
A: 20
B: 12
```

or

```
A: 10 20
B: 10 12
```

This solution works with both formats.

First, build a dict of lists with all scores:

```
all_scores = {}
while choice == 'av':
    if schClass == '1':
        with open("scores1.txt", 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                name, scores = li.split(':', 1)
                name_scores = all_scores.setdefault(name, [])
                for score in scores.split():
                    name_scores.append(int(score))
```

Then calculate the average (convert to sum to float in order to get exact average):

```
averages = {name: float(sum(scores)) / len(scores)
           for name, scores in all_scores.iteritems()}
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: @KURUN: the only append in my code will be applied to a list. This list will be initialized in an empty dict.

Comment: top one, that's the first one and it cant be changed

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append', I don't get whqt this means

Comment: @KURUN: you are applying .append to a str object. Not in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear; in other words, *what do you mean* with **adding more than one integer** to a dictionary key? This part is confusing because your code

```
diction1[name] = int(score) + diction1[name]**
```

seems to imply you'd like to add a string (`score`) to an integer (`int(score)`), which is impossible. If it's to add them side by side in a list so that, given a score of '4', the result is `['4', 4]`, then all you have to do is change the last few lines to this.

```
if name not in diction1:
    diction1[name] = [score, int(score)]
```

Also, eumiro's other changes to your code ***are good advice***, so keep them in mind and read the docs if you're unsure of how any of it works.

Answer (score -1):

Make `diction1` hold a [list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

```
if name not in diction1:
    diction1[name] = [score]
else:
    diction1[name].append(int(score))
```

Comment: `diction1.setdefault(name, []).append(int(score))`

Comment: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: @KURUN: That's because you put a string inside of it. Put a __list__ inside the dict.

Comment: @KURUN: Read the link to the python docs posted. I'm not a babysitter.